# J2Me swipe image left and right

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, swipe

I am learning Java Program for Mobile, I am trying to create a program thru which I can show images on screen by dragging from left to right, or right to left.

I have touch screen mobile, no harrdware keyboard.

I am trying the below code in which I have two forms and I want to show the other form when I swip the fingure on screen.

```
    import java.io.IOException;



import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class ImageDisplay extends MIDlet{
 private Display display;
  private Form form1,form2;
  private Image myImage1,myImage2;


  public void startApp(){
      display = Display.getDisplay(this);
      form1 = new Form ("Image Display");
      form2 = new Form("Second Image");
      try {
        myImage1 = Image.createImage("/bgscaled.jpg");
        myImage2 = Image.createImage("/spla77sh.jpg");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      form1.append(myImage1);
      form2.append(myImage2);
      display.setCurrent(form1);
      display.setCurrent(form2);
  }




  public void pauseApp(){

  }


public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional){
      notifyDestroyed();

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a way to be notified by an `LCDUI Form` when a screen swipe happens.
You can add "Next" and "Previous" buttons and change the forms when the buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/) instead of the `Form` screens as `Canvas` has various methods (e.g., `pointerDragged`) that can be used to determine touch, release and dragging actions.

Using `Canvas` can be a lot of work though (because your code will be responsible for every pixel that is drawn on the display). However, you may find [J2ME Polish](http://www.j2mepolish.org/) useful to transfer your `Form` UI to `Canvas`. (I'm not sure, but J2ME Polish might also take care of the swiping behaviour you are looking for, too.)